# How do I call a function from another .cpp file into the file where my int main() is?

Tags: c++

So my program requires me to make a function in one file, and call it into another.

I have one file called convertdays.cpp like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int convertdays(int, int, int); 

int convertdays(int month, int day, int year)
{
int date; 
date = year * 1000 + month * 100 + day; 
return date;
}
```

Then I have another file where my int main() stuff is, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
int day, month, year; 

cout << "Please enter the month: " << endl; 
cin >> month; 

cout << "Please enter the day: " << endl;
cin >> day; 

cout << "Please enter a year: " << endl; 
cin >> year; 

convertdays(month, day, year); //convertdays stays in red though.

//Still need to add a couple of more things but not necessary right now.

system("Pause"); 
return 0; 
}
```

How do I make this work where I can keep all of my functions in another file and call them in when I need them?

Comment: Read some about header files.

Answer (score 2):

Make a file called "convertdays.h", containing the function declaration:

```
int convertdays(int, int, int);
```

This is called a header file.

Then at the top of `main.cpp`:

```
#include "convertdays.h"
```

(It's a good idea to put the same thing at the top of `convertdays.cpp`, though not strictly necessary.)

Then when you build the executable, link `main.o` and `convertdays.o`.

Comment: I made another file called convertdays.h and put the declaration in there. 
I do not understand what "Then when you build the executable, link main.o and convertdays.o." means. 
I'm sorry I'm new so I'm not sure what to do there D:

Comment: @Burori That's explained in depth in the duplicate I used to clos your question